# How handle two grid in same window for appearing and disappearing with DoubleAnimation?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, grid

I think the title of my question is some mess! Sorry!

I have two Grid in same window. First named `loginBox` and second is `operationBox`. I want to disappear `loginBox` after validating user, using `DoubleAnimation` class and then operationBox will be appear in same time (during 00:00:01).

Scenario:

1. Grid named loginBox is showing when window shown. After user clicked on `btnLogin`, `loginBox` start disappearing using `DoubleAnimation` on it's `Opacity` property and in same time, `operationBox` will be appear using same technique.
2. After ending operation, user clicks on `btnLogout` and `operationBox` start disappearing and `loginBox` appearing by `DoubleAnimation`.

The problem is because `operationBox` grid is over`loginBox` grid, User can't do anything in `loginbox`! How ever `operationBox.Opacity=0` ;but nothing can do with `loginBox` grid at start up!

CODE:

```
<!--Login Box-->
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="loginBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="ورود" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="344,199,0,0" Name="btnLogin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsDefault="True"
                    Click="btnLogin_Click" >
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>                            
                            <Storyboard>                                
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="loginBox"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" 
                                    From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="operationBox"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" 
                                    From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
.
.
.
</Grid>

.
.
.

        <!--Operation Box-->
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="operationBox" Opacity="0" Visibility="Hidden">
...
            <Button Content="خروج" Height="23" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,324,0,0" Name="btnLogout" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnLogout_Click">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="operationBox"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" 
                                    From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />

                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="loginBox"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Opacity)" 
                                    From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

and finally, Sorry for bad grammar! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding operationBox.IsHitTestVisible="False"

**Update**

Try to add something like this

```
<Grid Grid.ZIndex="4" Background="Green" Opacity="0.4" Name="loginBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Grid.Opacity" Value="0.0">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: This make `operationBox` to be disable even when `Opacity = 1.0`, Problem is still alive! :(

Comment: I meant when the Opacity turns to 0.0 :)

Comment: Thank You Meleak for `ZIndex`! :D

Comment: Hehe! Sorry about that, copy/paste from my test project :-)